# Hibernate NonUniqueObjectException in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, constraints

I am getting a NonUniqueObjectException when adding a record from grails webapp.  This is happening because a user of the webapp is able to add records, and one of the fields they fill out is the PrimaryKey of the domain object/db table.  Hibernate will check the database to see if a record with that ID exists as soon as the domain object is created (AFAIK).  Thus it throws this error when it finds a conflict.

My first reaction was to add a new PK field onto the object that the user doesn't know about, such as a GUID.  While this works for many of the domain objects we have, we also have some domain objects that point to legacy tables that can't be changed.  This makes adding a column not practical for this purpose.

The next solution I have is to check the ID that the user passes in to the webapp and check if that already exists.  If it exists, pass back a kind message informing them that record already exists.  This solution will definitely work, but goes against the model of having all of the constraints on the domain object.  This could also be done in a try/catch for a similar result.

My question is, can I defer hibernate from checking if an object already exists in the database until save time?  The domain object has a unique constraint on it, and this constraint would be violated at save time and allow for a messages.properties message to be  called.  Also, any other ideas would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I made a mistake in the initial post.  The error is getting thrown when save is being called.  However, this points to a different issue.  The unique constraint on the domain object does not seem to get called.  The domain object somehow passes validation even though 'unique' is part of the domains ID.  Does this mean that constraint 'unique' on the ID field of a domain object is not validated in the same way that it is validated on other objects?

Comment: When is the exception being thrown now if not at save time?

Comment: Woops, I made a mistake.  This is occuring when calling save.  I guess thats what I get for making a post based on over-the-shoulder debugging vs running locally.  I'll update the post and rephrase the question.

Comment: Are you using save(flush:true)? The constraint is only validated upon attempting to commit the transaction (once the entire controller action is finished) or upon explicit requests to flush.

Comment: def saved = domain.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
Its running the custom validator I have created, so it must be getting to that logic.

Comment: I will just be catching the NonUniqueObjectException in my base SaveDomain method, then process it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the onSave() method in grails Domain Classes? Maybe that can help.

Comment: I don't think there is an `onSave()` method in Grails.